# Scala(Lift) lazy val inside Option or Box

Tags: scala, lift, monads, lazy-evaluation

I've a small problem using **Options** and **Lazy Evaluation** together .
for example when I try this code in the REPL I got the following

```
lazy val a = 3+3
```

REPL says:

```
a: Int = <lazy>
```

which is very cool, but ..

```
val b = Some(a)
```

REPL says:

```
b: Some[Int] = Some(6)
```

Looks like **Some** has to **evaluate the argument** before putting it into an Option :(

also

```
val b = Box !! a
```

evaluates to

```
b: net.liftweb.common.Box[Int] = Full(6)
```

the same effect :(

is there any workaround this, I just need an Option with a lazy val inside, if I could achieve the following it would be great

```
b: Some[Int] = Some(<lazy>)
```

Note:

I made some research before asking, and I found that **scalaz** has something called **LazyOption** , interesting but I couldn't use it :(

Any Help !

Comment: You could use `lazy val b: Option[Int]` or `Option[() => Int]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @senia `Option[() => Int]` made the trick

Answer (score 4):

When you execute: `val a = Some(b)` you are forcing `b` to be evaluated since `a` requires a value. If you don't want the evaluation to be deferred, you will need to make `b` lazy too.

```
scala> lazy val b = Some(a)
b: Some[Int] = <lazy>
```

Comment: you are right, but I must evaluate the Option itself early (I have to pass it to a call by value function)
so I can't use your solution .. an Option with a function inside like what senia said made the trick, 

Thanks anyway @jcern :)